# How to set the IEDriverServer.exe through command line in protractor

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, protractor

I would like to set the IEDriver executable path via command line while using protractor. I am using the following command, but it is not considering path to the IEDriver executable.

```
cd > protractor --seleniumArgs "['-Dwebdriver.ie.driver=../selenium/IEDriverServer.exe']" conf.js
```

I am getting the error:

```
var template = new Error(this.message);
               ^ UnknownError: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.ie.driver system property; for more information, see http://code.goo e.com/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver. The latest version can be downloaded from http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.ht
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried a lot and finally got the solution. Here is the solution..

We need to provide the IEDriver path in JSON string format at command line like

protractor ***--seleniumArgs "{webdriver.ie.driver:'../selenium/IEDriverServer.exe'}"*** --seleniumAddress "http://localhost:4444/wd/hub" conf.js

Make sure that we have to pass the --seleniumAddress either in conf.js or as command line argument.